# Finding the first and last number descending in an ascending list

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to find a way to write a program that will take in "n" terms and find out if it is ascending. If the list is not ascending, find the FIRST number that violates this order and print it's index location, i, then find the LAST number that violates it also.

ex: 2 3 4 2 3 2 3 4 1 - 
The outputs should be: element#4 is descending && element#9 is LAST descen

EDIT: I have solved how to find the FIRST number just not the LAST number

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num, inputNum, i;
    int nextNum=0;
    int violator1=0, violator2=0; 
    int elementNum1=0, flag1=0;
    int elementNum2=0, flag2=0;

    cout << "Enter how much numbers you want to enter in list: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> inputNum;

        if (inputNum >= nextNum){ 
            nextNum = inputNum;
        }
        else {
            flag1 = 1; /*The flag is set to '0' when the next number in      list has descended*/
            violator1 = inputNum;
            if (elementNum1 == 0) /*This condition will only run once because elementNum == 0 only once*/
                elementNum1 = i+1;
        }
    }

/*The flag value is determined within the loop to find the descending value*/
    if (flag == 0){ /*If the flag is UNchanged ie = 1*/
        cout << "These numbers are in ascending order." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "These numbers are NOT in ascending order." << endl;
        cout << "Element Number '" << elementNum << "' was the violating number." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and so does it work? are you sharing a good solution with us or do you have a question?

Comment: where are flag and elementNum declared in the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this one out.

To find the last violator in a list that has descended at one point, you must initialize a new flag and set it to change AFTER the first violator is found.

In my example above, the condition that element1 == 0 should be false after the first violator is found. Once that condition has failed, there needs to be a else statement that changes the new flag to something other than one and a new element2 variable that changes the index number every time a violator is found.